Neovim kickstart.nvim set tabstop to 4 for specific languages
I am using kickstart.nvim that includes some plugins such as treesitter. My init.lua has set tabstop and shiftwidth to 4 but this gets overrided.
In most cases it sets good settings but with HTML it sets tabstop to 8 which is unworkable on my screen. Typing :set tabstop in the file returns tabstop=8. How do i override this?
